# Последовательный вывод значений строк из MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, шаблоны

Есть фрагмент php, который обрабатывает переменные и выводит их в html. Цикл for выводит нужное количество записей, но все с наибольшим id (в моем случае 2 записи и обе с id=2), пытаюсь найти что-нибудь на счет подобного вывода, но пока безуспешно. Как сделать так, чтобы записи выводились поочерёдно и, если возможно, в обратном порядке?

```php
for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $getPosts = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT id FROM main_news WHERE id = '".$i."'");
    $postsArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getPosts);
    if(empty($postsArray['id'])){} else {
        foreach ($postsArray as $key => $value) {
            $queryContent = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM main_news WHERE id = '".$value."'");
            $resultContent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryContent);
        }
    }
}
$titleData = $resultContent['title'];
$sDescrData = $resultContent['small_descr'];
$timeStampData = $resultContent['timestamp'];
```

Comment: Вы действительно делаете несколько тысяч запросов к sql серверу за раз?

Comment: Да, многовато взял. Но если подскажете способ, как перебрать в районе 100 записей по другому - буду признателен.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна задача, но можно сделать примерно вот так:

```
$limit = 100;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM main_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " . $limit;
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
$posts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

foreach ( $posts as $post )
{
    /* Ваш код */
}
```

В `$limit` можно указать максимальное количество записей.

`ORDER BY id DESC` - означает, сортировать по id по убыванию значения.